# xpath of nth td in dynamic table in Selenium/Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have a dynamic table and I need to get all the values under the column "Date/Time? I'm unable to get to the /td containing Date/Time. The Td ID and Class names are all dynamic

```
<document>
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head id="Head1">
  <body>
   <form id="form1" action="RunReport.aspx?ReportPath=%2fxxxxxx%2fChange+Log&ReportName=Change+Log&ReportOutput=--" method="post" name="form1">
    <div/>
    <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ var theForm = document.forms['form1']; if (!theForm) {     theForm = document.form1; } function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {     if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {         theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;         theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;         theForm.submit();     } } //]]> </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/xxxxxxxx/WebResource.axd?d=V7QB9aA-CMKBf_It9wv5y2DqZbRLrb5ffBwJnLkaYDr5pU-NN0s1ZPyMlic7TalUdeqQfQg0f0hBQ5vc5FRF6TGqLTthE4DKA30A-L1LPCg1&t=635418606520000000"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/xxxxxxxx/ScriptResource.axd?d=ZQO5N5aOeLdEjEooaJaTyKww9aony6pg5nLqvVGBchaBRFjQEDHDikotXjab4lpgUsn8rNEgGqrrEmvFvTEJh9XNGP0OvUXTFQk6ZnGiqxCgD6yxZEIZNQeIUFyY7s0UJiH9S_XEit5ruUgYEwmnGToVkDm1twhe03OvidFuqGs1&t=7e632e9f"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/xxxxxxxxx/ScriptResource.axd?d=TraUIU0pF-vc5erOeo272dRc6jvvl-tp1IhH8icmW9Pqh-XyqQGubtk3taZPhhwGJyBEJq2uA1HlRhC55tsZ3PBPoT81bFotHP5mZF_KuY_2NJVoyMZznUTOBX5aqbBYnW9p4FEn3lnTyUpAjLCwlpk17z9yYmrw8ErPm6dTXg0LDVW1Jt40I6C1yk-hY_j70&t=7e632e9f"/>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="/xxxxxxxx/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=10.0.30319.1&Name=ViewerScript"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/xxxxxxxx/ScriptResource.axd?d=ZgCktqsR0I_2fhh-iIO4Abgy21lP5uMQNwtUzd_UyFfIprbIySdOXIPYBkpeZLT76IM5l0FiTvM__QYNu9JorZxtU13SyIYAffijp3IaAfJimLPcVFjaytrZe-noWDW4P0ZdWdc7kR8Vn5mci2VdV2Lj86BByElGhI9fC7p5o8k1&t=7e632e9f"/>
    <div/>
    <div/>
    <script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[ Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('Scriptmanager1', 'form1', ['fReportViewer1$ReportViewer','','fReportViewer1$Toolbar','','fReportViewer1$DocMap','','fReportViewer1$ctl10$ReportArea',''], [], ['ReportViewer1$ctl10$ReportControl$ctl00',''], 90, ''); //]]> </script>
    <noscript> &nbsp;Your browser does not support scripts or has been configured not to allow scripts. </noscript>
<span id="ReportViewer1_ReportViewer">
  <div id="ReportViewer1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;" onactivate="if ($get('ReportViewer1_ctl04') != null && $get('ReportViewer1_ctl04').control != null) $get('ReportViewer1_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();" onclick="if ($get('ReportViewer1_ctl04') != null && $get('ReportViewer1_ctl04').control != null) $get('ReportViewer1_ctl04').control.HideActiveDropDown();">
      <div id="ReportViewer1_HttpHandlerMissingErrorMessage" style="border-color:Red;border-width:2px;border-style:Solid;padding:10px;display:none;overflow:auto;font-size:.85em;">
      <span id="ReportViewer1_ctl03">
      <input id="ReportViewer1_ctl11" type="hidden" name="ReportViewer1$ctl11" value="ltr"/>
      <input id="ReportViewer1_ctl12" type="hidden" name="ReportViewer1$ctl12" value="standards"/>
      <div id="ReportViewer1_AsyncWait" style="background-color: White; opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: none; top: 29px; left: 0px; width: 1049px; height: 0px; z-index: 1000; visibility: hidden;"/>
      <div id="ReportViewer1_AsyncWait_Wait" style="cursor: wait; background-color: rgb(236, 233, 216); padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black; display: none; position: absolute; z-index: 1001; visibility: hidden; top: 0px; left: 441.5px;">
      <input id="ReportViewer1_AsyncWait_HiddenCancelField" type="hidden" value="False" name="ReportViewer1$AsyncWait$HiddenCancelField"/>
```

The below table id is on the same level as the above last input Id

```
<table id="ReportViewer1_fixedTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;">
<tbody>
<tr style="background-color:#ECE9D8;">
<tr id="ParametersRowReportViewer1" style="display:none;">
<tr style="height:6px;font-size:2pt;display:none;">
<tr>
<tr>
  <td style="vertical-align:top;width:25%;height:100%;display:none;">
  <td style="display:none;width:4px;padding:0px;margin:0px;height:100%;vertical-align:middle;background-color:#ECE9D8;">
   <td style="height:100%;vertical-align:top;">
  <div id="ReportViewer1_ctl10" style="height:100%;width:100%;overflow:auto;position:relative;">
  <div id="VisibleReportContentReportViewer1_ctl10" style="height: 100%;">
  <div id="P7d543a84a5b9486884b84551ef9c3d9d_1_oReportDiv" style="WIDTH:100%;direction:ltr" dir="LTR">
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td id="P7d543a84a5b9486884b84551ef9c3d9d_1_oReportCell">
     <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tbody>
       <tr>
      <tr>
       <td>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
         <tbody>
          <tr>
           <td style="vertical-align:top">
             <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="WIDTH:176.06mm;min-width:176.06mm;HEIGHT:241.30mm;">
             <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td style="vertical-align:top">
                <table class="Ada2aa9230a6045f4858a262591be2439124xB" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="WIDTH:176.06mm;min-width:176.06mm;HEIGHT:241.30mm;">
                 <tbody>
                  <tr>
                   <td style="vertical-align:top">
                    <table class="Ada2aa9230a6045f4858a262591be2439122" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" cols="10">
                     <tbody>
                      <tr height="0">
                       <tr valign="top">
                        <td style="HEIGHT:6.35mm"/>
                          <td class="Ada2aa9230a6045f4858a262591be243941c">
                             <td class="Ada2aa9230a6045f4858a262591be243945c">
                                <div class="Ada2aa9230a6045f4858a262591be243945">Date/Time</div>
                                   </td>
```

I searched online and tried this xpath and it didn't work. Any help is appreciated

```
List<WebElement> getDates = driver
    .findElements(By
    .xpath("//table[@id='ReportViewer1_fixedTable']//tr[contains(td[11], 'Date/Time')]"));

    for (int i = 0; i < getDates.size(); i++) {
        String strDateFrmRslt = getDates.get(i).getText();

    }
```

I cannot seem to post this question as I need to add more details so I am repeating my question here again
I have a dynamic table and I need to get all the values under the column "Date/Time? I'm unable to get to the /td containing Date/Time. The Td ID and Class names are all dynamic

---

SOLUTION:
If anyone is interested. Thanks to Ian Robert's post about the xpath I was able to get all the text from the table using //table[@id='ReportViewer1_fixedTable']//tr/td[3]
 and then I got the DateTime values from there.

Comment: If (as your code sample suggests) you know it's always the 11th column, why not just `//table[@id='ReportViewer1_fixedTable']//tr/td[11]`, or am I missing something?

Comment: I tried this and I still get only 1 row...

Comment: Actually your post helped me solve my problem.. I went about getting the text of each td[1], [2] etc and found that td[3] gave me all the text from the table.. so I trimmed that text to get only the DateTime fields and I am good .. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this xpath.

```xml
//table//td/div[contains(text(), 'Date/Time')]/..
```

This xpath looks for a `td` that contains a `div` that contains the text "Date/Time", and then goes back up one level to the `td`, without needing to know anything about ids or classes.

The problem with the xpath that you tried is that (1) it's depending on an id in the table, and (2) it's looking for a `tr`, not a `td`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the `tag` containing `Date/Time` is a `div` not `td`

Comment: @Saifur that's actually irrelevant, it will still work because `text()` ignores inner html.

Comment: @Saifur was that your downvote?  If so, can we get that reversed?

Comment: I would love to change it to upvote of course. I just wanted to test it from my side. Don't get me wrong but I was not aware about that. Can you provide any info I can I test that?

Comment: I copied OP's `html` and added closing tags and tested your `xpath` does not return me anything but I changed the `td` to `div` works as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: @Saifur -- turns out I was wrong.  Oops.  I've corrected the answer, it should work now.

Comment: Still deserve upvote for correcting the errors. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Thank you both for debugging.. but I'm still not getting anything when using  .xpath("//table//td/div[contains(text(), 'Date/Time')]/.."));

Comment: Have you verified the page has completely loaded before you try to find the element?  (Like using a WebDriverWait?)

Comment: Actually I now did a System.out.println("The no of rwos " + getDates.size()); and I get 1 row but I wanted all the rows from under the 'Date/Column'.... Your answer for the xpath did help me locate the element..I will mark your answer... But any ideas on why I am not getting all the rows?

Comment: Mmmm... Yes.  It's because I helped you to select the wrong thing.  To help you do what you want to do will be a bit more complicated, but first you need to post your entire html table;  right now your question only contains part of it (down to the `td`) and so I can't see the rest of the rows and how they're structured.  Can you put your whole dynamic table in your code sample?